# format string with a variable size vector of arguments (e.g. pass vector of arguments to std::snprintf)

Tags: c++, printf

I'm looking for a way to format a string with a variable-size vector of variables. What do you suggest is the best way of doing this?

I already know about std::snprintf and std::vsnprintf but unfortunately none works out of the box for my problem. Also a solution with recursive templates wont work for me because I can't rely on the input format being fully defined at compile time.

Here is a sample interface for the function I'm trying to implement.

```
std::string format_variable_size(const char* format, const std::vector<int>& in) {
std::string out{};
....
return out;
}
```

Example input and output:

```
const char* format = "My first int is %d, my second int is: %d, my float is: %d";
std::vector<int> in = {1,2,3};
```

the format_variable_size would return

```
out = "My first int is 1, my second int is: 2, my float is: 3"
```

Another example:

```
const char* format = "My first int is %d, my second int is: %d";
std::vector<int> in = {1,2};
```

the format_variable_size would return

```
"My first int is 1, my second int is: 2"
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked into [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)?

Comment: Use array or tuple, not vector.  You are discarding compile time information by using vector.

Answer (score 2):

If you have nothing against using [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), I think the following might work :

```
#include <numeric>

std::string format_variable_size(const char* fmt, std::vector<int> args){
  return std::accumulate(
    std::begin(args),
    std::end(args),
    std::string{fmt},
    [](std::string toFmt, int arg){
      return fmt::format(toFmt, arg);
    }
  );
}

std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
std::cout << format_variable_size("[{}, {}, {}]\n", v);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only specifier you use is `%d`, then you can easily do a loop and manually replace with the value coming from the vector. Alternatively, you might consider defining your own replacement token (for example `###`) to simplify parsing.

Also, if you can live with relatively small vector size (say maximum numbers), you could simply do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> copy(in);
copy.resize(10);
std::snprintf(buffer, buffer_size, 
    copy[0], copy[1], copy[2], copy[3], copy[4],
    copy[5], copy[6], copy[7], copy[8], copy[9]);
```

- If you format string contains less %d than the size of passed vector, then only the first ones will be outputted.
- If the size match exactly, you get the expected result.
- If the number of `%d` is greater than the input vector and up to the size of the copy, extra %d will be outputted with 0.
- If you have too much %d, then the behavior is undefined.

  - If the format string is internal, this might be acceptable but if it come from user or a file, it is better to validate the string (in which case, manually processing might be attractive)

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty solution, since we can't get `std::vector`'s size at compile time:

```
template <std::size_t... I>
std::string
format_variable_size_impl(const char* format, const std::vector<int>& in, 
                          std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    // Determine the necessary buffer size
    auto size = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, format, in[I]...);
    std::string out(size + 1, 0);
    std::sprintf(out.data(), format, in[I]...);
    return out;
}

std::string 
format_variable_size(const char* format, const std::vector<int>& in) 
{
    if (in.size() == 0)
        return format;
    if (in.size() == 1)
        return format_variable_size_impl(format, in, std::make_index_sequence<1>{});
    if (in.size() == 2)
        return format_variable_size_impl(format, in, std::make_index_sequence<2>{});
    if (in.size() == 3)
        return format_variable_size_impl(format, in, std::make_index_sequence<3>{});
    if (in.size() == 4)
        return format_variable_size_impl(format, in, std::make_index_sequence<4>{});
    if (in.size() == 5)
        return format_variable_size_impl(format, in, std::make_index_sequence<5>{});
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The real problem is that vector shouldn’t be used in this case.  A better alternative might be array or even tuple.