# format string with a variable size vector of arguments using fmt

Tags: c++, fmt

I'm looking for a way to format a string with a variable-size vector of variables. How to do it?

I've already read [format string with a variable size vector of arguments (e.g. pass vector of arguments to std::snprintf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642240/format-string-with-a-variable-size-vector-of-arguments-e-g-pass-vector-of-argu)

and I like the code of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57642429/20266935, but unfortunately, the code does not work, because `fmt::format` works with constexpr strings.

So I modified this function using `fmt::runtime` and it compiles, but I believe `std::accumulate` cannot be used with `fmt::format`, because it changes the string in a loop, one `{}` by one `{}` and the library does not like this.

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::string format_variable_size(const char* fmt, std::vector<int> args){
  return std::accumulate(
    std::begin(args),
    std::end(args),
    std::string{fmt},
    [](std::string toFmt, int arg){
      return fmt::format(toFmt, arg);
    }
  );
}

std::string runtime_format_variable_size(const char* fmt, std::vector<int> args){
  return std::accumulate(
    std::begin(args),
    std::end(args),
    std::string{fmt},
    [](std::string toFmt, int arg){
      return fmt::format(fmt::runtime(toFmt), arg);
    }
  );
}

int main()
{    
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    std::cout << format_variable_size("[{}, {}, {}]\n", v); 
    std::cout << runtime_format_variable_size("[{}, {}, {}]\n", v); 
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/337cGEh6d

Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: This doesn't seem feasible, since the size of the vector needs to be known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the experimental `dynamic_format_arg_store` API:

```
#include <fmt/args.h>
#include <vector>

std::string runtime_format_variable_size(const char* fmt, std::vector<int> args){
  auto store = fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store<fmt::format_context>();
  for (int arg: args) store.push_back(arg);
  return fmt::vformat(fmt, store);
}

int main() {    
  auto v = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
  auto s = runtime_format_variable_size("[{}, {}, {}]\n", v);
  fmt::print("{}\n", s);
}
```

This prints:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7a79a4d8o

Comment: Cool! Thanks. I'll check it out in a minute